# Como obter uma imagem de um resource

Tags: visual-basic-6

Quero chamar uma imagem com um botão pelo *Visual Basic 2010 Express*, no *Visual Basic 2008*, utilizava esse código:

```
picMyimage.image = My.resource.onomedaimagen
```

Até então funcionava como queria, porém no *Visual Basic 2010* não está funcionando, 
queria saber como chamar uma imagem pelo botão com essa nova versão.

Comment: Você quer pegar uma imagem do computador e colocar em um PictureBox pelo botão? Ou você quer colocar a imagem no resource e puxar de lá para o PictureBox pelo botão? Pode [edit] a sua pergunta e adicionar mais detalhes.

Comment: Desculpas Faz e tempo que eu estou procurando. isso tenho imagen na pastas de resource e quero faser um pequeno slider,tenho uma picturebox boto um botão quando clicar nesse botão a imgen passar pra outra entendeu!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para você pegar uma imagem do **Resource** e Adicionar no PictureBox, Faça da seguinte forma:

No OnClick do botão coloque:

```
{ pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.Untitledd; }
```

//Unitledd é o nome da imagem que está salva no resource